# Trouble with .listRowBackground()

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have Row View:

```
struct TestRow: View {
    
    var rowText: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(rowText)
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "heart.circle.fill")
        }
        .listRowBackground(Color.red)
 }
```

.listRowbackground work correctly, but if I add contextMenu, background changing to default (white) and don't changing from contextMenu :

```
struct TestRow: View {
    
    @State var rowColor: Color = Color.mint
    var rowText: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(rowText)
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "heart.circle.fill")
        }
       // .background(rowColor) -> this code working with contextMenu
        .listRowBackground(rowColor)
        .contextMenu {
                
                VStack {
                    Button {
                        //action code
                        rowColor = Color.red
                    } label: {
                        MenuButton(colorOrb: "red_circle", buttonText: "High")
                    }
                    
                    Button {
                        //action code
                        rowColor = .yellow
                    } label: {
                        MenuButton(colorOrb: "yellow_circle", buttonText: "Medium")
                    }
                    
                    Button {
                        //action code
                        rowColor = .green
                    } label: {
                        MenuButton(colorOrb: "green_circle", buttonText: "Normal")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

If I use .background(rowColor) instead .listRowBackground(rowColor) code work correctly, but I need colorise all row, not HStack only.

Comment: did you try to use listRowBackground outside foreach? ForEach(...) {...}.listRowBackground()

Comment: Yes, working, but how I can pass chosen color from TestRow View to ContentView, where my List forming?

Comment: This solution colorise whole List to chosen color, but I need to colorise each row to chosen color

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var color: Color
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    
    @State var items: [Item] = [Item(id: 1, color: .red),
                              Item(id: 2, color: .yellow),
                              Item(id: 3, color: .blue)]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {                
            List {
                ForEach($items) { $item in
                    TestRow(rowColor: $item.color, rowText: "\(item.id)")
                        .listRowBackground(item.color)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView2()
    }
}

struct TestRow: View {
    
    @Binding var rowColor: Color
    let rowText: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(rowText)
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "heart.circle.fill")
        }
       // .background(rowColor) -> this code working with contextMenu
       
        .contextMenu {
            
                    Button {
                        //action code
                        rowColor = Color.red
                    } label: {
                        Text("red")
                    }
                    Button {
                        //action code
                        rowColor = .yellow
                    } label: {
                        Text("yellow")
                    }
                    
                    Button {
                        //action code
                        rowColor = .green
                    } label: {
                        Text("green")
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, working thx!

Comment: @AlexS mark it as solved if it is :)